# What am I doing wrong with bottlepy + AngularJS + HTTP POST request

Tags: python, angularjs, cors, bottle

I'm trying to create simple Restful API with Bottlepy and creating client with AngularJS.

My issue is that when I send the form from Angular client, the post will go trough and everything is done, but the result still falls to .error(data) function in js side because:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/category/new. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8081' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

Here is my code for python API:

```
@route('/category/new', method=['OPTIONS', 'POST'])
def new_category():
    print request.forms.keys()
    if "name" in request.forms:
        name = request.forms.get('name')
        _name = db.query(Category).filter_by(name=name).first()
        if _name:
            return HTTPResponse(status=409)
        c = Category(name)
        print name
        if not c.validate():
            try:
                db.add(c)
                db.commit()
                return HTTPResponse(status=200)
            except Exception as err:
                traceback.print_exc()
                return HTTPResponse(status=500)
        return HTTPResponse(status=406)
    return HTTPResponse(status=400)
```

I also have CORS enabled like this:

```
@hook('after_request')
def enable_cors():
    print "Tried to enable cors"
    response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
    response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT'
    response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept'
```

And here is my angularjs service:

```
function addCategory(categoryName){
        var payload = $.param({name: categoryName});
        return $http({
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: apiBaseUrl+'category/new',
                    data: payload,
                    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
        })
        .success(function(data){
            return data;
        })
        .error(function(data){
            alert("Something went wrong");
            return data;
        });
   }
```

Any idea why I get Access-ControlAllow-Origin error?

In API log everything seems to be going just fine:

```
['name']
fourth
Tried to enable cors
10.0.2.2 - - [03/Aug/2015 10:44:02] "POST /category/new HTTP/1.1" 200 0
```

Comment: Can you add a dump of the HTTP packet received in the browser?

Answer (score 0):

Ah the issue seems to be that the bottlepy HTTPResponse doesn't send headers even with the hook.

So I created workaround to continue with my work. Hopefully there is a better way.

So what I basically created 2 new methods:

```
def set_cors(response):
    response['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
    response['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT'
    response['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept'
```

and

```
def setHTTPResponse(status, body=None):
    response = None
    if body != None:
        response = HTTPResponse(status=status, body=body)
    else:
        response = HTTPResponse(status=status)
    set_cors(response)
    return response
```

and then replaced every return HTTPResponse to return setHTTPResponse. e.g.

```
- return HTTPResponse(status=200)
+ return setHTTPResponse(status=200)
```